# Rails ActiveStorage: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm seeing the following error when attempting to use `.attach` to upload an image to a model in my Rails application.

I'm trying to

```
@company.best_landing_page_screenshot.attach(
        params.require(:company).fetch(:best_landing_page_screenshot),
      )
```

The issue is that the AnalyzeJob kicks in before the upload is completed.
Therefore, the AnalyzeJob (processed immediately in dev) fails.

The same issue is outlined here with no resolution: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39107

With Sidekiq inline testing turn off, it works fine:

```
@model.best_landing_page_screenshot.attach(
  params.require(:company).fetch(:best_landing_page_screenshot),
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (7.9ms)  SELECT `active_storage_blobs`.* FROM `active_storage_blobs` INNER JOIN `active_storage_attachments` ON `active_storage_blobs`.`id` = `active_storage_attachments`.`blob_id` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`record_id` = 15352 AND `active_storage_attachments`.`record_type` = 'Company' AND `active_storage_attachments`.`name` = 'best_landing_page_screenshot' LIMIT 1
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (4.4ms)  SELECT `active_storage_attachments`.* FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`record_id` = 15352 AND `active_storage_attachments`.`record_type` = 'Company' AND `active_storage_attachments`.`name` = 'best_landing_page_screenshot' LIMIT 1
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (1.1ms)  BEGIN
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (1.6ms)  DELETE FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`id` = 1311
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (5.0ms)  INSERT INTO `active_storage_blobs` (`key`, `filename`, `content_type`, `metadata`, `byte_size`, `checksum`, `created_at`, `service_name`) VALUES ('y19tkuk2xe6yqpbi404zq5nnuwp6', 'screely-1639331463764.png', 'image/png', '{\"identified\":true}', 1643856, 'ad3q6qj6AE7QVe5MvHUnig==', '2021-12-12 18:29:02', 'amazon')
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (6.0ms)  INSERT INTO `active_storage_attachments` (`name`, `record_type`, `record_id`, `blob_id`, `created_at`) VALUES ('best_landing_page_screenshot', 'Company', 15352, 220, '2021-12-12 18:29:02')
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (3.1ms)  COMMIT
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (5.0ms)  SELECT `active_storage_blobs`.* FROM `active_storage_blobs` WHERE `active_storage_blobs`.`id` = 218 LIMIT 1
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 715e6d4a-bbb6-4525-bf50-b2a9b6dbdf33) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fd807172aa0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://sendapostcardonline/ActiveStorage::Blob/218>>
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 53410b6b-3eef-4803-9b48-f1bf3e2f9c5c) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fd7f3047590 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://sendapostcardonline/ActiveStorage::Blob/220>>
  TRANSACTION (90.9ms)  BEGIN
  Company Update (84.4ms)  UPDATE `companies` SET `companies`.`updated_at` = '2021-12-12 18:29:02.899300' WHERE `companies`.`id` = 15352
Query Trace:
      app/controllers/admin/lead_enrichment_controller.rb:67:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (86.9ms)  COMMIT
  S3 Storage (1682.0ms) Uploaded file to key: xxxx (checksum: xxx==)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, what I noticed is that attaching attachments with `ActiveStorage` is not working properly when doing it inside a transaction. This applies to migrations, seeds or callbacks.

What I finally did to avoid my logic being wrapped inside a transaction is to run the logic inside a thread:

```rb
Thread.new do
  # your logic here
end.join
```